# python remove [' '] and reducing order

Tags: python, regex, string

I have successfully got a coding,but i am getting with `[' ']` which needs to be removed.It uses regex and obtains solution as:

```
['good benz']  instead of => good benz
nil                          nil  
nil                          nil
[]                           nil 
nil                          nil
['and 180']                  and 180
```

My coding:

```
import re
keywords=['car','bike','bus'] 

with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:            
        matches = []
        for word in line.split():
            if word in keywords:
                l=line
                matches.append(word)            
        if matches:
            a = ' '.join(matches)
            TEXT = a
            my_regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\b\s*(.*?),'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))))
            x = re.findall(my_regex, l)    
            print x
        else:
            print 'nil'
```

Text file for reference:

```
i havea bike good benz,
condition
yes
I have
Skoda Superb
yes good bike and 180,
```

Please optimise my code,Answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead of [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) if you only want the first match:

```
x = re.search(my_regex, l)
if x is not None:
    print x.group(1)
```

**Output:**

```
good benz
nil
nil
nil
nil
and 180
```

---

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) if you want to remove the `[]` from the output:

```
print ', '.join(x)
```

Comment: thanks,but my problem is how to output without [' ']

Comment: @user3914506 So, what is the expected output for `['good benz', 'bad benz']`?

Comment: i m much comfortable with re.findall(),i tried ur solution but still i get those [' '] ,i think my coding is including them not regex!